# Flat Resultset in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a query that returns a nested resultset because of the `contains` clause. Is there anyway I can flatten this and have the nested children at the parent level?

Query:

```
$results = $this->find()
            ->select(['Users.id', 'Profiles.firstname', 'Profiles.lastname', 'Profiles.title', 'Profiles.city', 'Profiles.state'])
            ->contain(['Profiles' => function($q) use ($searchStr) {
                return $q
                    ->where(['OR' => [
                        'firstname LIKE ' => $searchStr . '%',
                        'lastname LIKE ' => $searchStr . '%'
                    ]]);
            }]);
```

Resultset returned:

```
--> 0(object)
    --> id 5
    --> profile(array)
        => firstname Sam
        => lastname Johnson
        => title CEO
        => city Champaign
        => state IL
```

I would like the profile data to also be at the same level as `id`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`map`](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::map) method as described in [Query Builder: Queries are collection objects](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#queries-are-collection-objects).

```
$results = $this->Users->find()
  ->select(['Users.id', 'Profiles.firstname', 'Profiles.lastname'])
  ->contain(['Profiles'])
  ->map(function($row){

    $row->firstname = $row->profile->firstname;
    $row->lastname = $row->profile->lastname;

    unset($row->profile); // Remove this if you want to keep the 'profile' array.

    return $row;

  });
```

Additionally, you can use this same approach with [virtual fields](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-fields):

`App\Model\Entity\User`

```
protected function _getFirstname () {
  return $this->_properties['profile']['firstname'];
}

protected function _getLastname () {
  return $this->_properties['profile']['lastname'];
}
```

`App\Controller\UsersController`

```
$results = $this->Users->find()
  ->select(['Users.id', 'Profiles.firstname', 'Profiles.lastname'])
  ->contain(['Profiles'])
  ->map(function($row){

    // Right side of the operator will call User::_get*()
    // Left side of the operator will set the property to the object

    $row->firstname = $row->firstname;
    $row->lastname = $row->lastname;

    unset($row->profile);

    return $row;

  });
```